# Adding new countries to the possible delivery regions

Tags: overrides, core, countries

In terms of delivery, I am trying to split up the United Kingdom into its containing countries, England, Northern Ireland, Scotland and Wales.

Each country has different bank holidays and therefore different shipping logic can be applied to them.
At the moment I have found a solution which involves directly editing `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml`, this isn't the most elegant solution and would not work long term. I attempted to override the file by copying it to `/app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml` however that doesn't seem to work.

What I am wondering is there a long term, safe way to add a country without touching files which are not supposed to be touched?

Comment: I can try to suggest rewriting the `private static function _readFile($locale, $path, $attribute, $value, $temp)` method in lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php but, wouldn't say it to be "long-term".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Magento will not let you override Zend locale XML files in local.  This is due to the fact that the `_findRoute` method of `Zend_Locale_Data` specifically looks within the folder the file is in to build it's path to load files from.

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Data/' . $locale . '.xml';
```

What Magento *does* allow you to do though, is override the `Zend_Locale_Data` class itself, meaning you can rewrite the `_findRoute` function itself.

You can copy the file `lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php` to `app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data.php`.  Once you've done this, you'll be in a world of pain, as it'll now be looking for all the XML files in your `app/code/local/Zend/Locale/` folder instead of `lib/Zend/Locale/`.

You can alter the beginning of the `_findRoute` function to be something like:

```
private static function _findRoute($locale, $path, $attribute, $value, &$temp)
{

    // load locale file if not already in cache
    // needed for alias tag when referring to other locale
    if (empty(self::$_ldml[(string) $locale])) {

        // check for file in our local folder first
        $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Data/' . $locale . '.xml';
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {

            // added additional check in to check orignal lib/Zend/Locale folder
            $filename = Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/Zend/Locale/Data/' . $locale . '.xml';
            if (!file_exists($filename)) {
                #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("Missing locale file '$filename' for '$locale' locale.");
            }
        }

        self::$_ldml[(string) $locale] = Zend_Xml_Security::scanFile($filename);
    }
    ....
```

This will then look in `app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/` for XML files to load first, meaning you can place your updated `en.xml` in there.